# Eclipse - How to set default System Library

Tags: java, eclipse

Workspace default JRE shows the one that I set via `Window -> preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`. 
 But by default, the project has JRE System Library as Execution environment `[JavaSE-1.6(jre6)]`. 
Why doesn't JRE System Library make Workspace default JRE as the default System Library? And how can I change it to default System Library?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open 'Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs' and check that the JRE/JDK you want to use is listed - add it if it is missing.

Open 'Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments' and look at the entry for 'JavaSE-1.6'. Change the 'Compatible JRE' to the one you want to use.

Comment: perfect. I knew only the first part. Thank you @greg-449